# Apache Map Custom Domains to folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically, I have a web app - **www.mydomain.com/webapp/**, with folders:

- **www.mydomain.com/webapp/folder1**
- **www.mydomain.com/webapp/folder2**
- **www.mydomain.com/webapp/folder3**

Now I want to use these custom domains to access:

- **acustom.com** -> www.mydomain.com/webapp/folder1
- **otherdomain.com** -> www.mydomain.com/webapp/folder2
- **somedomain.com** -> www.mydomain.com/webapp/folder3

I knew I need to create CName records & point to **mydomain.com**. But now I don't know how to configure my server to resolve these custom domains then assign to the right folder.

Please help me, thanks

Comment: You'll probably get better help configuring your web server if you let people know what kind of web server it is.

Comment: thank, basically, I'll use Apache (or/and nginx); seems the solution involves to both vitural host, htaccess & PHP to setup, right?